# how to display something if the answer is 24

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create an output that displays "that's correct" if the input is 24 and "wrong" if the input is something else.
This is a school project

```
    <script>
      function getText(id){
        var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
        return text;
      }
      function showReply(id, reply){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = reply;
      }

      function reply(){
        var textFromUser = getText("myTextField");
        var reply;
        if (reply == "24") {
          reply = "that is correct";
        } else {
          reply = "wrong"
        }

        showReply("output", reply);
      }

    </script>
```

This is what I have so far.
As I am a beginner pls forgive me for my sloppy code. thx in advance

Comment: You probably wanted to check against `textFromUser` and not `reply` in your if-statement

Comment: It's confusing to use variables with the same name as the function.

Comment: to display some output to user, you can use `alert('message')` to show 'message'. Later, when you ll be advanced programmer, there are a lot of ways to do it. F.e. check dialogs/modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function getText(id){
        var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
        return text;
    }
    function showReply(id, reply){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = reply;
    }

    function reply(){
        var reply = getText("myTextField");
        if (reply == 24) {
            reply = "that is correct";
        } else {
            reply = "wrong"
        }
        showReply("output", reply);
    }
```

```html
   <input type="text" id="myTextField" onkeyup="reply()">
    <p id="output"></p>
```